# Marketing cloud Tracking Time conversion day light saving

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have job record

Select JobID, DeliveredTime from _Job where JobID=75XXX1

This give me :
DELIVEREDTIME : Oct 5 2021 2:06AM (Central Standard Time (CST) Time Zone, but do not observe Daylight Savings Time (DST)) (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323225&type=1)

The tracking for this job shows : 05/10/2021 10:06 ( I am in Amsterdam/Brussels)

I run a sql activity (below) where i try to convert this time to my time (CET) **today**  . I get 5/10/2021 9:06:00 AM

```
Select
T1.JobID as JobId,
CONVERT(datetime,(T1.DeliveredTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'),0) as SentTime,
T1.EmailName as EmailName,
T1.EmailSubject as Subject,
T1.FromName as FromName,
T1.FromEmail as FromEmailAddress,
T1.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID as TriggeredSendDefinition,
T1.EmailID as EmailID,
T1.AccountID as AccountID,
T1.DynamicEmailSubject as DynamicEmailSubject,
T1.EventID as EventID
From
    _Job T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

So there is 1 hour difference. I assume this is because of day light saving which happens in nov in US.

The problem i have jobs which have run post day light saving run have correct time and job which have run before day light saving have wrong time.

how can i change my sql so that it gives me right time always

Comment: On further investigation and using the Naveen blog (https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/dynamic-salesforce-marketing-cloud-email-send-based-upon-country) , i convert my time in UTC. I see the problem comes because Amsterdam is UTC + 2 in Oct and UTC + 1 in Dec as the day light saving changes on 30th Nov. any ways i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to my question.

Thanks to ["https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/its-timezone-finally-real-convert-function-salesforce-jack-hobbs/"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/its-timezone-finally-real-convert-function-salesforce-jack-hobbs/) from Jack Hobbs
and "https://bornsql.ca/blog/dates-and-times-in-sql-server-at-time-zone/"

The problem was source timezone .

Orginal SQL :

```
Select JobID, 
     DeliveredTime as del0,
     DeliveredTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' as Deltim2 
from _Job where JobID = 7XXX9
```

I was first using 'Central Standard Time' as mentioned by salesforce marketing cloud on article (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323225&type=1)

> "Marketing Cloud servers use the Central Standard Time (CST) Time
> Zone, but do not observe Daylight Savings Time (DST)."

***This was a mistake. i should have used 'Central America Standard Time' instead of 'Central Standard Time'***

Modified SQL:

```
Select JobID, 
     DeliveredTime as del0,
     DeliveredTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' as Deltim2
from _Job where JobID = 7XXX9
```

So when i modified my sql, the dates were correct for jobs before day light saving change and after it also

Thanks a lot guys , you dont spend the morning finding this as i did.